# Android 2.2 (level 8) httpclient.execute consistent timeout

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, timeout

I'm attempting to receive a response from a restful service, but receive a timeout.  I am able to connect with the browser on my emulator, as I have configured an access point on the emulated device to pass through proxy (at work).  Network seems to be fine.  I've added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

The code is as follows:

```
public String getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
    String content = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Execute HTTP Get Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 4096);
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        content = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        content = e.getMessage();
    }
    return content;
```

I know I should return a stream, but for the sake of just displaying some string values in a TextView widget, will suffice, so I'm just using the string to experiment.  It consistently hangs on .execute, no matter what URL is passed.  I've passed valid IP's as well, with nothin' doin'.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: As an update to this, I was able to connect with this code when outside of the proxy, i.e. directly connected.  Do I need another permission listed in the manifest or some specific directive to use proxy from the code?  It definitely seems to be the proxy that is gumming things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Put it at the top of the class.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", <your proxy host name>);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", <your proxy port>);
```